# Flutter could not find correct Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have been facing this issue since last 2 days, never got this type of error before due to Provider.
[It is giving me this error that there is no Provider in the above Widget but I have used provider in the previous page which is working completely fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ofvA.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX8QL.png)

I have tried all possible methods to solve it but the problem is not getting solved.

Main.dart
[Used MultiProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh7kJ.png)

[This is the line which is causing the error. I have also used similar way to access User class functions in the previous page and it was working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9gJJ.png)

Comment: use Proveder.of<UserClass.User>(context, listen: fase); as you assign in main

Comment: it would be easier of you could post part of the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Please don't show the code as images. Copy past the code and improve the question.